# how to supporting SEF URLs in my component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-sef-urls, sef

i am newer to joomla component please help me.

i create one small joomla component as per user requirement. and its run perfect. now i have one issue in this component i am trying to provide sef support in this component but i have no idea how to do.

i read this link - http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#Routing_URL.27s

and i create one router file in my component.
in router.php file.

```
<?php
function joomBuildRoute( &$query )
{
       $segments = array();
       if(isset($query['view']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['view'];
                unset( $query['view'] );
       }
       if(isset($query['id']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
                unset( $query['id'] );
       };
       if(isset($query['layout']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['layout'];
                unset( $query['layout'] );
       };

       return $segments;
}

function joomParseRoute($segments)
{
       $vars = array();
      $app =& JFactory::getApplication();
       $menu =& $app->getMenu();
       $item =& $menu->getActive();
       // Count segments
       $count = count( $segments );
       //Handle View and Identifier
       switch( $item->query['view'] )
       {

             case 'message':
                   $id   = explode( ':', $segments[$count-1] );
                   $vars['id']   = (int) $id[0];
                   $vars['view'] = 'message';
                   break;
       }
       return $vars;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there any error? Is Joomla .htaccess file active on your host and URL rewriting activated on your backend?

Comment: Thanks for replay. it's not shown any error. my url rewrite successfuly. but its not redirect into this page. when i click on button its rewrite this url but not redirect on to that page. its display first page all time. how to redirect on that page? Thanks.

Comment: Does you component requires layout set? If yes, set layout variable in case 'message'.

Comment: we need a bit more info about your component. what do your current urls look like and how you want your sef urls too look like?

Answer (score 0):

thanks,

its not done.

some other problem here.

page url rewite but its not redirect on that.

suppose here url when i click on message button is 
JOOMLA/joom/index.php/component/joom/message/default

means its rewrite but not display message page.

thanks.